# How to import classes and function that are not exporting in Python module

Tags: python, import, module

I am using the mne python package: https://github.com/mne-tools/mne-python/

We are doing some custom work and need to create a custom class.

This is what I need to export although it is not exported as a module from the package.

`from mne import RawArray, BaseRaw, verbose, logger, _validate_type, _check_option`

My background is JS and I would normally just src the node_modules for this. How is this done in Python?

Full Code WIP

````py
import mne
import lzma
import numpy as np

from mne import RawArray, BaseRaw, verbose, logger, _validate_type, _check_option 


def save(original_file_path, new_file_path, channels, compress=True, overwrite=False):
    original_raw = mne.io.read_raw(original_file_path, preload=True)
    info = original_raw.info

    print(channels)
    testfile = open("./test.txt", "a")
    testfile.write(repr(channels))
    testfile.close()


    new_info = info.copy()
    new_raw = CustomRawArray(channels, new_info)
    f = None

    if compress:
        f = lzma.LZMAFile(new_file_path, mode="wb")
    else:
        f = open(new_file_path, "a")

    f.write(new_raw)
    f.close()    


class CustomRawArray(BaseRaw):
    @verbose
    def __init__(self, data, info, first_samp=0, copy='auto',
                 verbose=None):  # noqa: D102
        _validate_type(info, 'info', 'info')
        _check_option('copy', copy, ('data', 'info', 'both', 'auto', None))
        # dtype = np.complex128 if np.any(np.iscomplex(data)) else np.float64
        orig_data = data
        # data = np.asanyarray(orig_data, dtype=dtype)
        if data.ndim != 2:
            raise ValueError('Data must be a 2D array of shape (n_channels, '
                             'n_samples), got shape %s' % (data.shape,))
        if len(data) != len(info['ch_names']):
            raise ValueError('len(data) (%s) does not match '
                             'len(info["ch_names"]) (%s)'
                             % (len(data), len(info['ch_names'])))
        assert len(info['ch_names']) == info['nchan']
        if copy in ('auto', 'info', 'both'):
            info = info.copy()
        if copy in ('data', 'both'):
            if data is orig_data:
                data = data.copy()
        elif copy != 'auto' and data is not orig_data:
            raise ValueError('data copying was not requested by copy=%r but '
                             'it was required to get to double floating point '
                             'precision' % (copy,))
        logger.info('Creating RawArray with %s data, n_channels=%s, n_times=%s'
                    % (dtype.__name__, data.shape[0], data.shape[1]))
        super(RawArray, self).__init__(info, data,
                                       first_samps=(int(first_samp),),
                                       dtype=dtype, verbose=verbose)
        logger.info('    Range : %d ... %d =  %9.3f ... %9.3f secs' % (
                    self.first_samp, self.last_samp,
                    float(self.first_samp) / info['sfreq'],
                    float(self.last_samp) / info['sfreq']))
        logger.info('Ready.')    
    ```
````

Comment: Python has no concept of (not) exporting names. If the names are defined, you can just import them. What happened when you tried?

Comment: What, **exactly**, is the problem you are encountering?

Comment: Just so you know, any name that starts with a single underscore means it's a "private" attribute, use at your own risk

Comment: There is code in the package I need to access and pull in to override. I am working on a compression module that builds off of mne. However they force arrays to be float32s which is the problem. The imports listed in the question from mne are not actually exported from the package but I need to bring them in. How do I directly reference these files? Do I need a VENV and then a path?

Comment: This might be an issue that Python jargon and JS jargon do not match. What do you mean when you say the imports "are not actually exported from the package"? As mentioned before, Python has no concept of exporting things – *everything* in a package is "automatically exported". Do you mean the objects are not part of the top-level package? Are you aware that you can import from subpackages as well?

Comment: In Javascript you have a package.json and when that installs you get a node_modules folder that is full of packages. Often times I can actually import files from these via a direct path link into the directory instead of a standard automatic import X. Many package makers actually have exported files that are used to create larger exports but in JS in the standard import you only get the larger export which would be like from X import Y... well I am saying I need from Y import Z type of thing.

Comment: Are you looking for something like ``from mne.io import RawArray``? You can only import things from modules/packages that actually contain then.

Comment: Woooooow man Python... Okay I guess I will have to go to the mne repo and then copy paste all of these dependencies for RawArray that I have no intention of changing.